# How to separate elements when render a list with .map() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am rendering a list that contains some perfumes. These perfumes have some categories, some perfumes have more than one category associated with it.

I would like to know how I can separate the categories with a `bar` if the perfume has more than one category?

With the image below it is easier to explain:

[image]

In the first perfume, it has 3 categories, so the bars are separating the items.

Here's my code I put into [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/render-list-space-fm0ng?file=/src/App.js)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace the following Code in your Card.js

```
<span>{item.categories.map((category) => category)}</span>
```

with

```
<span>{item.categories.toString().replaceAll(',', ' / ')}</span>
```

With this solution you dont need to **map()** your Array.

--

Alternatively you could use the built-in **join()** function.
In this case your code looks like this:

```
<span>{item.categories.join(' / ')}</span>
```

Comment: Hey Yannick, with `join` works perfecty for me. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS to achieve the desired result.

We employ the `:not()` selector on and combine it with the `:first-child` to only apply our style to elements after the first. From there we use `::before` psuedo element to apply a "|" on the left side of the element.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
} 

li:not(:first-child)::before {
  content: "|";
}
```

```html
<h2>Product 1</h2>
<ul>
<li> Cat 1 </li>
<li> Cat 2 </li>
<li> Cat 3 </li>
</ul>
<h2>Product 2</h2>
<ul>
<li> Cat 1 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `Array.join()` instead of map in `Card.js`

```
import React from "react";

const Card = (props) => {
  const { item } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{item.categories.join(' / ')}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```